# Unable to create a new remote session

Tags: automation, appium

I am using Appium for automation testing. Whenever I am running it, after the application launch, my app gets killed.

This is the error log I am getting:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'IN-6J1QPN2-10', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at JWProxy.command 
System info: host: 'IN-6J1QPN2-10', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

Comment: You can check your appium server log for the exact reason of the testing failure.

Answer (score 2):

Please Run your appium server with Admin permission. Enable "Allow Session override" flag under the "Advance" tab in Appium server before start. After this, run the below mentioned commands.

```
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server

adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
```

Additionally you can run if you have "Unlock" and "Settings" installed in Test device for Appium.

```
adb uninstall io.appium.unlock

adb uninstall io.appium.settings
```

Now, run your test cases and let me know.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222)